# Provisioning doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.developer.parent-application-identifiers entitlement

Tags: xcode, apple-appclips

I've created App Clip for my application , but i can't auto sign it , i am getting 2 errors :

> Automatic signing failedXcode failed to provision this target. Please
> file a bug report at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com and include
> the Update Signing report from the Report navigator.
>
> Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: x.x.x.clip"
> doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the
> com.apple.developer.parent-application-identifiers entitlement.

When i create new app with new appclip its working fine , but when i try it on my current app its not working same issue again and again , I've tried almost every solution in the community same issue .

I've posted my question here after i've spent days trying to fix this issue.

```
xCode : Version 12.5 (12E262)
MacNook pro : 2020
macOS Big Sur 11.2.3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two values that need to match up. First, locate the provisioning profile Xcode is using for your App Clip (they're in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`) and inspect it by highlighting the file and pressing space. The parent ID value in there:

[image]

..has to match the same field in your `.entitlements` file in your App Clip target in Xcode. If it doesn't you can just edit the entitlement manually.

Comment: will , after doing ur solution the app is signed , but i got another error after the build is success and trying to install in on my device `This app clip's bundle identifier is not prefixed by its parent app's bundle identifier.`

Comment: well , i had to register the app clip id manually, then trigger the auto sign provision profile , now its worked

Answer (score 0):

Pietro is correct.
I would just add that when the error mentions the bundle identifier (from the app or the app clip), they mean the FULL bundle identifier (TeamID + bundle id).

The Team ID prefix looks like `ABC123DEF456` and the bundle identifier like `com.example.app`.
This means you must make sure that when you head for [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com), you must make sure that you create the App ID for the app clip **with the same TeamID prefix as the parent app**!

This way, the full bundle identifier should look like this:

- for the app: `ABC123DEF456.com.example.app`
- for the app clip: `ABC123DEF456.com.example.app.clip`.

A good way to check that is to go in the Finder to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`, find the provisioning profile for the app clip and quicklook it to check that.